# Line separator/break in discord embded

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have the following discord embed:

```
    message.reply({
    content: '',
    embed: {
        color: 11416728,
        author: {
            name: 'xx know-it-all',
            icon_url: 'https://xx.png'
        },
        description: '',
        footer: {
            icon_url: client.user.avatarURL,
            text: '© xx Network'
        },
        fields: [
            {
                name: '1st Line',
                value: '2nd Line',
            },
            {
                name: 'MAKE THIS JUST A SPACER',
                value: 'MAKE THIS JUST A SPACER',
            },
            {
                name: '5th Line',
                value: '6th Line',
            }
        ]
    }
})
```

I am trying to figure out how to create a spacer of sorts. I have tried using a html space, blank space, and alt code space. None of them seem to work. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

The issue is discord is returning the field as null, so it's not taking it when I use the invisible html space or putting \n

Comment: Where are you trying to use the break?

Comment: Here: name: '...',. I get value can't be null

Comment: Don't think you can use line breaks on that field. Try _ \n _ without the spaces

Comment: Wait, you want a line separator/break or give it more space, like a few pixels of margin?

Answer (score 11):

I got it!

All I needed to do was use the C/C++/Java encoding version of the invisible space

```
\u200B
```

Reference: https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200B/index.htm

This can come into use for other people looking to make embeds look more clear as discord complicates it

Answer (score 3):

Discord.JS has a method [`.addEmptyField()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RichEmbed?scrollTo=addBlankField) that uses `\u200B` to display a empty line.

```
    message.reply({
    content: '',
    embed: {
        color: 11416728,
        author: {
            name: 'xx know-it-all',
            icon_url: 'https://xx.png'
        },
        description: '',
        footer: {
            icon_url: client.user.avatarURL,
            text: '© xx Network'
        },
        fields: [
            {
                name: '1st Line',
                value: '2nd Line',
            },
            {
                name: '\u200B',
                value: '\u200B',
            },
            {
                name: '5th Line',
                value: '6th Line',
            }
        ]
    }
})
```

Appears to be working here.

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/8580e891d90833daabc7686d5ae860da.png

This is an example of how it would look like.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, I figured out you can get around this by using the [backspace escape-sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C) too:

`\b`

This is useful if you want your embed fields formatted in a 2 x 2:

```js
fields: [
  {
    name: 'Field1',
    value: 'Value1',
    inline: true
  },
  {
    name: 'Field2',
    value: 'Value2',
    inline: true
  },
  {
    name: '\b',
    value: '\b',
    inline: true
  },
  {
    name: 'Field3',
    value: 'Value3',
    inline: true
  },
  {
    name: 'Field4',
    value: 'Value4',
    inline: true
  },
]
```

Comment: This must've worked in the past, now, we get a weird thing:

https://i.gyazo.com/e38dcd512109e767d5bfeb5979271823.png