# Discord embed message with tab indentation automatically removed

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So i am sending an embedded message in python with discord.py

```
val = "bullet points:\n \u0009• test data"
embed.add_field(name = "Test", value = val, inline=False)
```

However the whitespace is automatically removed (no indentation)

I have tried using spaces etc but no luck. Is there another way of achieveing indented text which is embedded.

PS sending a normal message with the param var is shown correctly indented, the issue only occurs when the message is embedded

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50373020/line-separator-break-in-discord-embded)?

Comment: @Zsolt that's for a blank line, I'm looking for an indentation

Answer (score 2):

Code blocks prevent other markdown from being processed. If you don't want to use code blocks. You can use IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE: "　"
I copied it from here https://jkorpela.fi/chars/spaces.html

Answer (score 1):

discord's formatting allows you use three ` to make a code block. Much similar to Stack Overflow.

```

```
Test
    Test
        Test
```

```

Comment: But i would like to use an embedded message if possible as i can add footers icons pictures etc

Comment: update `val` to start and end with three of the graves. iirc embeds can include the formmating. I know the discord.js can, dunno bout discord.py. But i'd assume so, as both are using discord's api.

Comment: Thanks that worked. Is there a way so that the text is not a different background to the embed because like this it treats it as code. If not, still better than it was :)

Comment: un-fortunately not really. There's possible workarounds, such as creating an image dynamically with the text. Or *possibly* using the no-break-space `&nbsp;` instead of spaces.